# Help! Help! My IQ!

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #2: IQ Puzzle Parody](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7376/)</sub>

---

Help! I'm trying to score a 100 from this online IQ test but can't figure out some of the questions. Below is an example, with the three answer options at the bottom. What kind of help do you think I should be enlisting here?

[image: IQ puzzle grid]

Comment: rot 13(xvyyre fhqbxh, boivbhfyl.)

Comment: I've worked out that rot13("fvtangher" zngpurf nyy guerr bcgvbaf, yrsg gb evtug naq gbc gb obggbz), but it looks like rot13(gur avar 3k3 oybpxf arrq gb or erneenatrq, bgurejvfr gur obggbz ebj zhfg erhfr n qvtvg: V va ebj 9 pby 1 = 2, A va ebjf 8-9 pby 4 = 13 be 31, G va ebj 9 pbyf 8-9 = 15 be 24 be 42 be 51).

Comment: @EdMurphy No rearranging necessary. Sounds like you're on the right track.

Comment: ([rot13](http://rot13.com))V oryvrir guvf gb or n Pvcure Xvyyre Fhqbxh (gung vf, n Xvyyre Fhqbxh jvgu gur nqqvgvbany ehyr gung jr arrq gb svther bhg gur nffbpvngvba orgjrra qvtvgf naq yrggref). Ohg vg frrzf yvxr gurer'f abg rabhtu vasbezngvba gb fbyir vg whfg sebz gung... V'ir gevrq nqqvat gur rkgen ehyr "rnpu obk orybj zhfg or zngpurq ol n obk va gur fbyhgvba", ohg rira jvgu gung V'z abg pbaivaprq gurer'f rabhtu vasbezngvba.

(V nyfb abgr gung gur obkrf orybj fcryy "vag f[d]hner" jura abg bireynvq, naq - nf Rq abgrq - "fvtangher" jura bireynvq. V'z abg fher ubj rvgure bs gubfr vf eryrinag.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is the completed grid:

> [image: final grid]

How can we get there,

> First, we overlap the three answer choices given and we see a meaningful word; **signature**. We map those letters to corresponding numbers in the grid.

> [image: Letters] [image: Numbers]

Now,

> this is a *normal*(?) killer sudoku puzzle.

> [image: 1]

> It is easy to start with cages that have a lower sum, and then it flows <s>effortlessly</s> (well, yes, it requires some effort).

> [image: 2]
>  [image: 3]
>  [image: 4]
>  [image: 5]
>  [image: 6]
>  [image: 7]
>  [image: 8]
>  [image: 9]
>  [image: 10]
>  [image: 11]

> Finally, convert them to the letters again.

Wait, is that all? We saw some red dots in the sketch. What was that?

> [image: final answer]

Oh!

> **GENIUS**.

Thanks. Nice puzzle by the way :)